# JS - How to make Boxes collapsable in AdminLTE ( is using Bootstrap) when Content dynamical loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the AdminLTE Skin from https://almsaeedstudio.com/
I want to load the page content dynamically when clicking on the menu on the left side. I made this via jQuery:

```
<li><a href="javascript::;" onclick="$('#Content').load('./pages/test.php');"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Test</a></li>
```

But when in Test.php is a collapsable box like this:

```
<div class="box box-primary">
<div class="box-header with-border">
<i class="fa fa-medkit"></i>
<h3 class="box-title">Test Box</h3>
<div class="box-tools pull-right">  
<button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="box-body">TestContent</div>
</div>
```

The box is not collapsable when I click on the button nothing happens. 
When I don't load the Content dynamically the button is usable. What is the matter here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same situation.
When I was looking for a workaround I've managed to discover what seems to be the real problem.

If you take a good look at app.js you'll see that there are many activate methods that scan the page to find out if a component is been used and then transforms or injects the behavior for the component.

That seems to be the case to boxes (Collapsable and closeable ones at least).

If you reload the script ($.getScript(app.js)) the box will work, but unfortunately other components will stop working (sidebar and control-sidebar).

If you want just the boxes to work inside de content-wrapper, one way is to call:

```
$.AdminLTE.boxWidget.activate();
```

You can do this on the $(document).ready() function of your content.
I'm still finding a better way to do this, but as far as boxes go, this should do the work.

Regards,
Jonatan Neves

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and ended up changing app.js so that the box widget listeners are on the document instead of the actual elements found when activate() is called. This guarantees dynamically added elements will be found:

```
  $.AdminLTE.boxWidget = {
    selectors: $.AdminLTE.options.boxWidgetOptions.boxWidgetSelectors,
    icons: $.AdminLTE.options.boxWidgetOptions.boxWidgetIcons,
    activate: function () {
      var _this = this;
      //Listen for collapse event triggers
      $(document).on('click', _this.selectors.collapse, function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        _this.collapse($(this));
      });

      //Listen for remove event triggers
      $(document).on('click', _this.selectors.remove, function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        _this.remove($(this));
      });
    },
    //...
}
```